# Does the Doctor have a black list of times and places?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, paradox

In one of the latest episodes of Doctor Who (*[The Angels Take Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Angels_Take_Manhattan)*)

> the results of a paradox forces the Doctor to stay out of that time and place permanently.

Is this the only such place, or does the Doctor keep a list of places that he can't go?

Comment: Spoilers... spoilers...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Given the Doctor's prodigious intellectual capacity and the TARDIS' ability to map the whole of space and time, the two of them more than likely keep a mental list of places they can't go easily and why.**

- Indeed, if there are places the Doctor can't go, he is just as likely to be the cause of such an event. If he isn't then, he will probably investigate it so he can either map it or untangle it if he can.
- Judging from his reaction to fixed points in time (he abandons and avoids Captain Jack Harkness, for instance) he does not appear to be fond of them, perhaps they bring back bad memories (such as the Great Time War) or perhaps he simply doesn't like things he cannot view or change. He is a TimeLord, all Time and Space are within his purview, in his opinion.
- The TARDIS will, on occasion bring the Doctor to points in time which may go in either direction. These are those side trips he usually hasn't planned and has no idea why or how he ends up in these places.
- While the Doctor likes to pretend he is frail and mortal, I suspect he is able to do things both in conjunction with the TARDIS as well as his species natural abilities we rarely see utilized.

Comment: Captain Jack isn't a fixed point in time - he is essentially frozen in time.  Rose messed up when she fixed him.  That's why he can't be killed and why the Doctor avoids him - he **shouldn't be** and it gives the Doctor the willies.

Answer (score 1):

Given the Doctor often has trouble remembering species he has encounted and planets he has been too, I get the impression the Doctor just senses/knows from experience these things. He is more sensitive to what is possible and what is not.

A common story principle is never solving the same problem the same way twice.  Travelling in time makes it to easy to repeat a task until you are successful (Ground hog Day style) and when the Doctor is not successful at something it's because the writer intended that to be the case.